# Is it time to reopen: How do I calculate gambling edge using average win?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing

A probability theory question ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/how-do-i-calculate-gambling-edge-using-average-win-closed)) was asked when this site was fairly new.  I suspect that the closure of this question might be a result of being asked during the website's infancy -- to me, while not a masterpiece, it doesn't seem off-topic (at least when compared to today's questions).

> Is there another reason this question is closed besides being off-topic (I understand the interface is limited)?

and if not...

> Could I encourage votes to re-open this question?

Comment: The questioner does not seem to have returned soon after the closure, unfortunately.

Comment: Now that the question has been reopened, let's close this one :-)

Comment: @mods: a `status-completed` would be nice here, I think.

Answer (score 6):

I was the second vote to reopen, mainly because (1) you asked and (2) no one really gave a reason for closing then or an argument for keeping it closed now.

I probably wouldn't have voted to close in the first place.  On the other hand, if I had stumbled across the question myself after closing, I probably would not have voted to reopen, largely because of lack of involvement of the asker after posting.  Knowing that you are interested in it reopening is enough to sway my vote.

Added December 3: For some time the question had 4 votes to reopen, but the votes expire after a few days, and it currently has only 1.

Comment: Now it has four.

Comment: It just became 5: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2611/revisions

Comment: Great!  Now I guess I should answer it (: